# BIRT: Adding multiple Category (X) Series

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, birt

I have a single dataset containing 4 columns, each showing the number of rejections for a quarter-year. A 5th column shows the Team to which those values belong.

Is it possible to add 4 fixed points on the x-Axis, each belonging to one of these columns? Then I could add the Team as the Y-Series. I'd like to see the evolution of each team in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing a (really short, really simple) loop which takes the values out of the four mentioned columns, one at a time, and creates four rows instead.

So the rows basically contain the Team from the original row (duplicated 4 times) and the Number of Rejections. So now instead of a Row with one team and four numbers, I have four rows, each with one team and one number.

I did this all in the report scripts (under "fetch"). Try it, it's really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:
http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1553-use-column-names-as-chart-xaxis/